# Measuring the level of centrality of a matrix

Tags: algorithms, matrix

I have simulated the moving and clustering of actors through Netlogo.  I colour actors with a score higher than 60 as red, lower than 40 as green, and others as blue. Now I need a measurement of the level of clustering of the chart that describes whether the green actors are scattered or clustered, and how well they are clustered. (Let's ignore the crosses and the circles and focus only on the squares in the chart)

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how these matrices differ, if at all, from datasets of 16 numbers each?  And if there's no difference, then we also need you to tell us how you would *quantify* "level of clustering," because there are many possibilities and the choice of an appropriate one depends on contextual information you haven't provided.

Comment: Thanks whuber. I have updated the question with more specifics.

Comment: That's very informative, thank you.  But it would help us find useful answers if you would also explain what the clustering is intended for or what it measures or what it might represent.

Comment: So this represents the clustering of people with different opinions on a subject. I am interested in that, after different treatments, how well would people with different opinions cluster and form consolidated opinion groups. So I need to calculate the overall level of clustering of the chart and compare different charts.